# crash course for Facebook SDK (Login and Post)

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

What am I supposed to use for a "Login with facebook"? I want also to create posts on the users wall and like subsites of my website if he votes them up.

I tried about 10 hours now. Still don't know how to begin. I find only specific answers but no answer on how to start.

The authentication I did like this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/

But I could also do it with http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/ the PHP SDK.

Which variant should I use? 
And how can I realize "I want also to create posts on the users wall and like subsites of my website if he votes them up."

I am not asking for the full code, just for hints how to start, what to use. The whole facebook documentation doesn't help to answer this, the most important and easiest questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you tell us what is the problem again? What do you mean by 'What am I supposed to use for a "Login with facebook"'?

For start up, I suggest you to read [this link](http://www.masteringapi.com/category/tutorials/facebook-tutorials/) first. It is a very good facebook tutorial on PHP SDK and Javascript. They also teach you how to post to user wall and checking on like status.

Hope this help!

Comment: Nice link, thank you!
My question is, which variant to get authentication / login the user in my website should I use. 
The variant with the PHP SDK or the other one where I create a link on my own :
"The authentication I did like this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/

But I could also do it with http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/ the PHP SDK."

So to post on the users wall I need the PHP SDK, so I think i should use the variant with the PHP SDK?

Comment: The server-side authentication or PHP SDK authentication is the same method. The first link you provide is the shorten version of PHP authentication. Using either one should get you through the process.

Comment: I was able to post to the wall now, but how is it possible to create a user like for a subsite of my website if he votes it up?

Comment: Better explained, how can I realize that the "vote up" button on my website is at the same time a "Like" button?
IF the user votes up a image on my website it should automatically determine that as he liked this page.

Answer (score 0):

You can also give these tutorials a try, covering the basics of facebook js/php sdk integration

http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-javascript-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/

http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-3-0-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/